# Dash Unable to Center Table Horizontally

Tags: plotly-dash

My code below reads in a small CSV file, defines the styles, and displays the output.
The H1 tag is centred, as expected.
But for some reason, my table is not centered horizontally.
What am I doing wrong?

```
df  = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
app = Dash(__name__)

hdg_style  = {'color': '#055d9c', 'text-align': 'center'}
tblh_style = {'backgroundColor': 'Linen', 'fontWeight': 'semi-bold'}
tbl_style  = {'textAlign': 'center', 'maxWidth': '1000px', 'border': 'thin #055d9c solid'}


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children="My Project", style=hdg_style),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        data         = df.to_dict('records'),
        columns      = [{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],
        style_cell   = {'textAlign': 'center'},
        style_header = tblh_style,
        style_table  = tbl_style)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I tried the CSS below to center the table horizontally, but it did not work.

```
style={'margin-left': 'auto', 'margin-right': 'auto'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include the margin attributes in your `tbl_style` definition, it'll center the table - it did for me in my test case:

```
tbl_style  = {'textAlign': 'center', 'maxWidth': '1000px', 'border': 'thin #055d9c solid', 'marginLeft': 'auto', 'marginRight': 'auto'}
```

I suspect your attempts with CSS modifications get caught up in the vagaries of Dash configuration of serving static css files.

Answer (score -1):

app.layout = dbc.Container(). In that, you put multiple dbc.Row. Then, dbc.Col in them. In these columns you put objects (your datatable). You can then align anything you wish moving objects by defining size and offset. Check official dash bootstrap components doc for the detail

Comment: dbc.Row and dbc.Col are an alternative worth pursuing down the road, but perhaps off-topic for OP's question of how to simply center the table.